# Using the field axioms of real numbers, prove that $y=\frac{1}{x}$ if $xy = 1$ and $x ≠ 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, axioms

My attempt: $xy = 1$ and $x ≠ 0 $

Multiplying by $\frac{1}{x}$

$xy \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{x}$

$y = \frac{1}{x}$

I am not sure if i used the field axioms correctly.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. How do expect to prove *something* starting from *no* hypothesis whatsoever? And the quastion should be understandable even by someone who hasn't read the title.

Comment: Do you mean : if $xy=1$, then $y= \dfrac 1 x$ ? If so, it is an axiom+def : "for every $x ≠ 0$, there exists an element, **denoted by** $\dfrac 1 x$, called the *multiplicative inverse* of $x$, such that $x \cdot \dfrac 1 x = 1$."

Comment: This is correct, but you should multiply on the left.

Comment: To me, this is basically being asked to prove a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is a bit confusing. If $x\in \mathbb{R}$, you should ask yourself what the *definition* of $\frac{1}{x}$ is. The  definition  that I imagine was given is that $\frac{1}{x}$ is *defined* to be the multiplicative inverse of $x$, i.e. $\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$, in which case 
$ xy=1$
implies $x^{-1}(xy)=x^{-1}$ and then by associativity, $(x^{-1}x)y=x^{-1}$ and finally by definition of inverses and the identity property of $1$, $(x^{-1}x)y=1\cdot y=y.$ So, $y=x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}$.